# NoMethod Error for window.use on tabs

Tags: watir-webdriver

I'm prototyping a script in irb and I'm running into a NoMethod error for '.use' when using the window switching api on tabs. Anything as simple as

```
b.windows.last.use


b.windows[2].use
```

Will not be respected and throw a`NoMethodError: undefined method 'use' for nil:NilClass` error while the window remains tabbed. If I drag the tab out to a separate window and run the same command it works as expected. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the window you want to use is a real a new window of browser, not a tab, than you can use these methods described in this [spec](https://github.com/watir/watirspec/blob/master/window_switching_spec.rb).I am not sure webdriver supports capturing a tab as a browser.